# Setting up VirtualenvWrapper on Ubuntu 12.04: Location of virtualenvwrapper.sh?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenvwrapper

I use Virtualenv and VirtualenvWrapper on my local machines and find them wonderful tools. I am trying to set the same up on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 12.04 server and Apache for my production Python applications.

Virtualenv is working fine. But I am having issues configuring VirtualenvWrapper. I have installed it via pip. `pip freeze` gives me

```
virtualenv==1.7.1.2
virtualenvwrapper==2.11.1
```

I have followed the instructions on the [documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

**NOTE: See Edit below** virtualenvwrapper was actually installed via apt-get. i did follow the rest fo the instructions though.

```
...
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
```

but when I try the next step

```
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I get an error

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

My `/usr/local/bin/` only has one file in it `django-admin.py`

The documentation states

> First, some initialization steps. Most of this only needs to be done
>   one time. You will want to add the command to source
>   /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh to your shell startup file,
>   **changing the path to virtualenvwrapper.sh depending on where it was installed by pip.**

How can i find the location of this file?

Using `find / -name "virtualenvwrapper.sh"` just outputs a list of `Permission denied` errors

Running `find / -name virtualenvwrapper` gives me

```
/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper
/usr/share/pyshared/virtualenvwrapper
/usr/share/doc-base/virtualenvwrapper
/usr/share/python/ns/virtualenvwrapper
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper
```

Any advice on how to find the file would be great

**EDIT:**

I actually installed virtualenvwrapper via apt-get due to an issue with my proxy

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper
```

Possibly this pits the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in a different place?

Comment: If you installed it within your `virtualenv` then that's where it will be, not in the system global `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: No, I did not install it in a virtualenv. I installed it globally. Have just uninstalled and reinstalled to confirm

Comment: `pip` should have created a log file.

Comment: Your recent edit is a game-changer.  Apt generally puts stuff in `/usr/bin`, not `/usr/local/bin`; but in this case, that's not the case at all, either.  You can see the list of installed files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualenvwrapper.list`

Comment: The file list is also visible at http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/virtualenvwrapper/filelist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `README.Debian` of the package you installed (and generally whenever you install an unfamiliar package).  It is in `/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper` and it tells you that the file you are looking for is installed in `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper`.

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/251378/where-is-virtualenvwrapper-sh

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to clarify in my situation "source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper.sh" would not work for me but "source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper" would.