# file path problems using pip and apt-get in local and production virtual environments.

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, apt-get

[I have had some issues installing python packages in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085226/setting-up-virtualenvwrapper-on-ubuntu-12-04-location-of-virtualenvwrapper-sh) when pip and apt-get have either used different install paths when installing python packages or look in different places for supporting packages.

I have recently encountered this again when installing MySQL-python using pip on my Mac but [specifying the path as detailed in this solution fixed the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12708157/1214163)

**My issue is:** I don't understand why pip and apt-get use different paths and when using one or the other will cause me future issues. Can anyone explain what is going on here? Is there a good article or resource anyone can point me to? This is an issue which seems to come up regularly around here but which is not immediately obvious.

I mostly use apt-get on my production server as pip has issue with the college firewall. If I now install MySQL-python with apt-get  on my production virtual environment will this cause me issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you try to download the source of the library and install it with the command line `python setup.py install --prefix=/your-path`?

Comment: I have it installed now. My question is that I would like to understand this process and the issues better. How can I avoid similar problems in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A terse explanation is given on the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Python). Basically, since python is used by the system, debian and its descendants try to separate platform-distributed python modules in .deb packages (dist-packages for "debbian distribution packages") from external packages you install with, say, setup.py which go in site-packages. To keep things confusing some tools stick things in dist-packages anyway and it seems like a fair number of them end up in /usr/lib/pythonX.X/.

The debian [Style Guide for Packaging Python Libraries](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide) is a good read.